# Task manager not ending process

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

As of late I've been unable to end the process for SoulseekQt.  The task manager isn't "killing it" nor is `taskkill /f /im`.  When I try the latter I get the following:

> "Error: The process “SoulseekQt.exe” with PID 5604 could not be terminated. 
>   Reason: There is no running instance of the task."

I'm assuming this is telling me the program is not operating so it can't be terminated.  However it does show up in tasklist so clearly it is running and using over 185K of memory.

After I post this I will reboot my computer to effectively end the program.  There has to be some reason though why this is all of a sudden happening. I don't know how to determine if the cause is SoulseekQt itself or Windows 7 (64-bit).

If anyone has any answers/can help in any way, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know what's the cause but with [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) you can kill any process you want.

Comment: So you can see the process SoulseekQt.exe in Task Manager, if so, if you add the Threads column what is the count?

Comment: I downloaded this one task killer program a couple of days ago, what a nuisance (did more harm than good).  Didn't work and I couldn't uninstall it, using it's own uninstall program.  Had to restore my computer to before I downloaded it to get rid of it.
I'd rather not go down the road of downloading/installing something that is going to cause me grief.

Comment: As for the second response re: threads column - I unfortunately don't know what you mean.

Comment: Seems that whatever was preventing SLSK from closing has now been fixed.  The one thing that changed was I removed my pending downloads from a user who was offline.  I can't be 100% certain but I'll take the win (so to speak).
Thanks to those who left comments trying to help.  Much appreciated.